# Appeal to reopen a closed question about Nanigans API

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I'm about to appeal to reopen a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122565/nanigans-server-side-api-call-from-php)

This question is:

- a specific programming problem
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

I see the question as pretty clear and it has all necessary data to make an answer. This is pretty particular programming problem. The example of URL where to make an API call is presented.

**This question is addressed directly to those developers who already worked with Nanigans Tracking API and could share their practice.**

And unfortunately I do not have more data to add to this question. This is only what I got from Nanigans documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: [**Minimal. Complete. Tested. Readable. Example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Of what your problem *actually is*. "What have you tried?"

Comment: There are many similar questions in cumunity, some of them closed but have answers and have a lot of votes:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns
etc. just put `example` in search and check. Mine question is similar, I need an example of particular issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Most people, when they claim that their question is on topic because it is

- a specific programming problem
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession

... have conveniently left out the remaining part of that Help Center article that explains why their question may be off-topic anyway.  It starts near the middle of the page, with the caption:

#### Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above.

... and then goes into some detail about why some questions may be closed, even though they might fit into the two bullets you listed.

---

For your specific question, I am wondering if there is not adequate documentation for this API, and if so, why not?  Stack Overflow is mostly about helping you with programming problems you are wrestling with, not about discovering someone's API, or substituting for their user manual, nor are we a proxy for some company's customer service.

If there is a user manual available for this API, you should try and avail yourself of it first.  If there isn't, try to contact the owners of the API and find out why.

Comment: Robert, there are plenty of other APIs discussions in Stack Overflow, does your answer mean that all of them should be closed and removed from Stack Overflow? Thank you.

Comment: No, just the ones where the author asks us to read the manual for them.

Comment: I do not ask you to read a manual, actually I do not have any. What I'm looking is, for somebody who already have some experience with them. Thanks.

Comment: This is another example where sites oficially use Stackoverflow as Customer Support site: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
Check the paragraph about support. And this is the link they pointed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geoip So your words are contradiction of what current Stackowerflow policy is.

Comment: That page says that *Maxmind does not provide support for free Geolite databases.*  They can point people to Stack Overflow all they like, but that does not mean Stack Overflow is an official support channel for them, nor does it prevent Stack Overflow from closing Geolite questions that are off-topic.

Comment: Robert Harvey check the list of question regarding Geo IP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742562/where-to-find-great-proxy-servers-for-testing-geoip-services and more which are pretty simmilar to mine, the only difference that mine is related to not-famouse, particular API. I really think that it's not fair. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 14):

It isn't a good fit in its current form:

> I need a working example in PHP of how to make the server-side call to Nanigans API.
>
> I suppose it should be a simple CURL call to URL like:
>
> ```
> http://api.nanigans.com/event.php?app_id=<APP ID>&type=purchase&name=sale&s2s=1&user_id=[Replace:user_id]&ut1=[Replace:email_hash]&unique=[Replace:order_id]&value=[Replace:value]
> ```
>
> Also it would be great to make a call without waiting the response, to make it faster.

Try to turn it into a real-world question. You mention that the API has documentation? Link to it. Point us to where it says which parameters it expects. Show some code you've tried (e.g. using `curl_exec()` etc.), how it doesn't work, and what errors you get (e.g. by looking at the output of `curl_error()`).

If it's a question not about the programming aspect of calling the API, but about the API's syntax or expected parameters, it should likely be posed to its developers and maintainers, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: The documentation has only the URLs to API and pixels to put them in page. An it is PDF format sent to me directly. There is no practical examples in it, and they do not provide any of them. I didn't tried any yet, this why I asked somebody to provide a possible example. There are many questions like that about FB API, Google API etc, and for some reason they are not closed, but mine was closed, why?